# Can you embed a font in HTML without linking to an external source?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I need to use a font in an HTML page but I also need it to work offline, when I have the project on my PC without internet connection. Since I can download the `.ttf` file from Google Fonts, is there a way to actually include the font without importing it from `fonts.googleapis.com`?

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly do that. Use the @font-face in your .css file

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontName';
  src: url('FontName.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('FontName.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('FontName.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('FontName.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('FontName.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('FontName.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

the URL would be specified accordingly, depending on what folder you have the font in, relative to the CSS file.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can include the font on your server/ local storage and use a local link, instead of the url.

```
@font-face{
    font-family: /*name here*/
    font-style: normal
    font-weight: 250
    src: url('') /* replace with local link/ format*/
}
```

See: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp for more detail